# File upload enctype= multipart/form-data not working in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I was trying to upload a file through form in PHP. Unfortunately the file upload is not working. It seems the file is not getting selected. Below is my code. I have replicated the original code in the below.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
            <form action="submit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Resume</label></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="cv" id="cv"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
</body>
```

submit.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['cv']))
    {
        $filename = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
        echo $filename;

        $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
        $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
        $allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.rtf','.pdf');
        // Rename file
        $newfilename = $file_basename.$random.'_cv'. $file_ext;
        $filepath = "resume/" . $newfilename;
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"], $filepath))
        {
            echo "moved";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "not moved";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "no file";
    }
?>
```

Whenever I run this code I am always getting the error `no file`.

Could anyone please help me to find where I am going wrong.

**Edit 1**

I have updated the code consolidating the answers commented.

submit.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['cv']))
    {
        $filename = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
        echo $filename;

        // $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,5);
        // $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
        // $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name
        // $allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.rtf','.pdf');
        // // Rename file
        // $newfilename = $file_basename.$random.'_cv'. $file_ext;
        // $filepath = "resume/" . $newfilename;
        // if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"], $filepath))
        // {
        //     echo "moved";
        // }
        // else
        // {
        //     echo "not moved";
        // }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "no file";
    }
  ?>
```

For now I am just commenting the file move code and just trying to get the file name. It's still showing `no file` error

Comment: where is `$random` defined?

Comment: Not related: Place your `<form></form>` outside of your `<table></table>`, not inside

Comment: @kerbholz — That is related. Error recovery from *that* error is painful. (Usually the form is moved outside the table leaving the inputs behind (and not associated with any form))

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting using `POST` but you need to test whether the file field is there and not empty - so essentially you test for `isset( $_FILES['cv'] )` etc ~ or you can use `!empty()` that tests if it is set and has a qualifying value that doesn't equate to zero or null etc

```
<?php

    $random=uniqid();
    $status=false;

    if( !empty( $_FILES['cv'] ) ){
        $obj=(object)$_FILES['cv'];
        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
        $allowed=array('doc','docx','rtf','pdf');

        if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && in_array( $ext, $allowed ) ){
            $filename=basename( $name ) . $random . '_cv.' . $ext;
            $filepath='resume/' . $filename;

            $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $filepath );
        }
        echo $status ? 'moved' : 'not moved';
    } else {
        echo 'bogus';
    }

?>
```

---

A working example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP: Upload resumé</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='cv' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

                $directory='c:/temp/resume';
                if( !file_exists( $directory ) ) mkdir( $directory, 0777, true );

                $random=uniqid();
                $status=false;

                if( !empty( $_FILES['cv'] ) ){

                    $obj=(object)$_FILES['cv'];
                    $name=$obj->name;
                    $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
                    $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
                    $allowed=array('doc','docx','rtf','pdf');



                    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && in_array( $ext, $allowed ) ){

                        $filename=basename( $name ) . $random . '_cv.' . $ext;

                        $filepath=$directory . '/' . $filename;

                        $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $filepath );
                    }

                    echo $status ? 'moved' : 'not moved';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Done the mentioned change. Still same result.

Comment: sorry about that - I missed that the file extensions in the `$allowed` array have the period - removed that and it should be ok

Comment: I commented all other codes for file uploading. I am just trying to get the file name of the selected file. But still showing the `no file` error.

Answer (score 0):

Just change in the submit.php file

```
 if (isset($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'])) {

    $random = rand(11111, 999999);
    $filename = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
    //echo $filename;

    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file extention
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')); // get file name

    $allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.rtf','.pdf');
    // Rename file
    $newfilename = $file_basename.$random.'_cv'. $file_ext;
    $filepath = "resume/" . $newfilename;
    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_file_types)){
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"], $filepath))
        {
            echo "moved";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Not moved";
        }
    }else{
       echo "File type invalid";
    }


}
else
{
    echo "no file";
}
```

And Done

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned. But no result.

Comment: I update full code above can you check, It should be work for you

Answer (score 0):

You should first look for the possible errors like this:

```
if (UPLOAD_ERR_OK == $_FILES["cv"]["error"]) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"];
    $real_name = basename($_FILES["cv"]["name"]);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "resume/{$real_name}");
} else {
    // process the file upload errors here
    var_dump($_FILES["cv"]["error"]);
}
```

Look for the errors. There could be a UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE or POST_MAX_SIZE limits, for example (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)).